# Trigonometry Limit Question

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am wondering if 1 get 1/0 for a limit i am calculating, is the limit necessarily infinity?

How to prove that the limit of $\frac{1}{\sin x}$ as x tends to 0 is is infinity or does not exist? And the limit of $1/\tan x$ is infinity or does not exist?

Comment: u can say limit does not exist.

Comment: the limit may be $\infty $, $-\infty $, or it may not exist. In fact, the limit of $\frac{1}{\sin x}$ as $x\to 0$ does not exist (and is thus not $\infty $).

Comment: why it does not exist? how to prove it?

Comment: The inequality $\sin x<x$ for $x>0$ will help you show that $\lim_{x\to0+} 1/\sin x = +\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to0-} 1/\sin x = -\infty$.

Comment: What about the cot x? Actually that is the part I am struggling with

Comment: You could use for both problem the fact that $\frac{1}{\sin x}=\frac{1}{x} \frac{x}{\sin x}$ and that, when $x\to 0$, $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1$ and, as a consequence, $\frac{x}{\sin x}\to 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\sin x=0$ and $\sin x>0$ for small positive values of $x$, you get
$$\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac1{\sin x} = \lim\limits_{t\to0^+}\frac1t=+\infty.$$
Similarly
$$\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\frac1{\sin x} = \lim\limits_{t\to0^-}\frac1t=-\infty.$$
Since the [one-sided limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit) are different, the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could also show that $\dfrac{1}{\sin\left(\frac 12\pi+2\pi n \right)} = 1$ and $\dfrac{1}{\sin\left(-\frac 12\pi+2\pi n \right)} = -1$ and there does not exist some real number, $L$, such that ${1, -1}\in (L-\frac 13, L + \frac 13)$